# new entries by one id

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a **table1** with fields `call_id, param0, param1, param2, ...param30` .
The param fields take values ​​from 1 to 100.

And there is a second table **table2** with fields `call_id, theme_code`
which Ineed to fill out from the first table,
The complexity of the task is that for one `call_id` I need to take each of these `param` as `theme_code`,
And if one of the `param` is null, then you don't need to create a new record for `call_id`

Example:
table1:

```
    callid   | par0 | par1 | par2 | par3 | par4 | par5 | par6 | par7 | par8 | par9 | par10 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    1234567  | 24   | 2    | null | 91   | 58   | null | 25   | 19   | 77   | 62   | null  |
```

table2:

```
callid   |  theme_code  |
------------------------
1234567  |  24          |
------------------------
1234567  |   2          |
------------------------
1234567  |  91          |
------------------------
1234567  |  58          |
------------------------
1234567  |  25          |
------------------------
1234567  |  19          |
------------------------
1234567  |  77          |
------------------------
1234567  |  62          |
```

Comment: Do you need a second table - can't you just unpivot the first, maybe as a view, so you aren't duplicating data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to just want to unpivot the columns from `table1` into multiple rows:

```
select callid, theme_code
from table1
unpivot (
  theme_code
  for par in (par0, par1, par2, par3, par4, par5, par6, par7, par8, par9, par10)
)
```

| CALLID | THEME_CODE |
| --- | --- |
| 1234567 | 24 |
| 1234567 | 2 |
| 1234567 | 91 |
| 1234567 | 58 |
| 1234567 | 25 |
| 1234567 | 19 |
| 1234567 | 77 |
| 1234567 | 62 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HHFiALtP)

You can read more about pivoting and unpivoting [in this article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1).

Unless `table1` is some kind of staging table, copying that data into `table2` would go against normalisation principles, and you might be better off just using that query when you need it, or creating a view based on it (which could be a materialised view).

If you really do want to put the unpivoted data into another table then you can use that query as the basis for an `insert` or `merge` statement.